# mysql define index via suggestion

Tags: mysql, indexing

i have a php/mysql application that i have logs of all select queries during all action in my project. i want to know is it possible to get any suggestion for any `select x, y from t1 where (con1 AND con2) OR con3 order by colx` that which columns must be index in my logs ?

i have many query like this also with joined. i heard `EXPLAIN` can help me to suggest for this query which columns must be index. i want to know how can i figure it out which columns must be index. multiple columen index, signle index. order by needs to be index and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index `con1` and `con2` as multiple-column index.
While `con3` as a single column index

```
INDEX (con1, con2),
INDEX(con3)
```

Comment: this is an example. i want to need a tools for suggest which col must be index. or if doesn't exist tell me rules

Comment: check the rules here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html